# how to add fonts

Tags: fonts

I downloaded Greek and Hebrew fonts to add them to Libre Office but after many attempts I do not manage to get them installed. I do it via nautilus and after adding the fonts in a map within truetype and run sudo fc-cache in the terminal but no fonts in Office.What is the right method?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What file type are these fonts? Where did you download them from? What *exactly* did you try to install them? Please [edit] your question to clarify these points.

Comment: Search for `how to add fonts` in the searchbox (top of this website) to yield for several results. Please tell us what you have tried and what type of error you receive.

Comment: Finally I managed to install them via nautilus.  So the problem is solved. Thanks.